# How to Make Google Jquery Library Async or Defer?

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to disable wordpress default jquery and load from Google library to speed up website and reduce latency for this Big File.

But Here i want to make it defer or async loading, So How we can do this ?

Here is code which i am using in my function.php file:-

```
//Making jQuery to load from Google Library
function replace_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.3');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'replace_jquery');
```

I have tried this in my `functions.php`, but it does not work:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" src', $tag );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What do you think in register a new js that calls Jquery?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/) to modify the HTML before printing.

`apply_filters( 'script_loader_tag', string $tag, string $handle, string $src )`

---

```
add_action( 'init', 'replace_jquery_src' );

/**
 * Modify loaded scripts
 */
function replace_jquery_src() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {

        // Remove the default jQuery
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

        // Register our own under 'jquery' and enqueue it
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js', false, '1.11.3' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}

add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_async_to_jquery', 10, 3 );

/**
 * Filter script tag output
 *
 * @param string $tag    HTML output
 * @param string $handle registered name
 * @param string $src    path to JS file
 *
 * @return string
 */
function add_async_to_jquery( $tag, $handle, $src ) {

    // Check for our registered handle and add async
    if ( 'jquery' === $handle ) {
        return str_replace( ' src=', ' async src=', $tag );
    }

    // Allow all other tags to pass
    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i am not a php expert, can you please modify my code and give me new code, So i can add directly in function.php file !!

Comment: I am using this code... But not working               `add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function ( $tag, $handle ) {

    if ( 'jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js' !== $handle )
        return $tag;

    return str_replace( ' src', ' defer="defer" src', $tag );
}, 10, 2 );`

Comment: That looks about right. Just double check what is showing in $handle. I imagine the $handle would be 'jquery' like you registered above

Comment: tried this and several other things, but not working. Also this question is marked this as Duplicate even other question is much more different than this !!

Comment: The above code is a working example. `$handle` is not part of the `$src` like you have it, it's the registered name

Comment: JQuery JS file handle is 'jquery-core'